# Retain animation effect on unhovering a div

Tags: html, css, onhover

I have a blue back grounded div that will be animated to top on hovering on it . I need the div to follow the same effect and reach its original position on UN hovering form it Source code attached . Should i write separate coding for it? The blue color div comes back very quickly when i UN hover it
HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">wrapper<div id="lion"><a href="#">Hover</a></div></div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper{ position:relative;top:30px;height:140px;width:150px;overflow-y: hidden;}        
#lion{position:relative;width:100px;height:50px;top:20px;padding:20px;  background-color: blue;}
#lion a {color:black;text-decoration: none;}
#lion:hover{transform: translateY(-70px);transition-duration: 2s;}
```

Comment: <div id="wrapper">wrapper <div id="lion"><a href="#">Hover</a>      </div></div> this is the HTML for my question

Comment: Please put your code into a snippet and tidy it. Maybe it's just me, but I find it quite rude of you to expect people to read what looks like "minified code".

Comment: Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krishnameg/3z9y1a7z/

Answer (score 2):

If you add `transition-duration: 2s;` to the `#lion`. The blue shape should transition back to original position when hover is removed. Use the css below. Also you can see it working on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chrustlesstulip/uka1ebqr/) jsfiddle.

```
#wrapper{     
    position:relative;
    top:30px;
    height:140px;
    width:150px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}        
#lion{
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    top:20px;
    padding:20px;  
    background-color: blue;
    transition-duration: 2s;
}
#lion a {
    color:black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#lion:hover{
    transform: translateY(-70px);
    transition-duration: 2s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you missing the transition property in #lion unhover. Try to add transition-duration in #lion selector. Now with your code, when hover #lion transition is 2 seconds, but in unhover is not duration and is not transition. Good luck